# How to access a member variable without instantiation, C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, static-members

Suppose I have class B which gets a value 'v' in the constructor from another class A. How can I read this value from class C?
Class C will be instantiated on demand, but A has created B and passed the 'v' already. 'v' will change in every instantiation.  I have tried to make 'v' static in Class B. Would it work? I could not implement it properly.

```
Class A {
 public:
 int* v;
 B b1;
 A(int* var) : v(var), b1(var) {};
}
```

How to access the same version of 'v' from a C class?
 I can define B and C however I like in order to achieve the goal. But I cannot change A for that purpose.

Comment: Please post some minimal code which replicates your question

Comment: can you write some snippet of your code??

Comment: C needs to have an instance B and have access to it's members such as via public accessor

Comment: @GIJoe not if they're `static` members

Comment: Confusing parts of the question: the title speaks of member variable without instantiation, which hints at class members, but the first sentence mentions "gets a value 'v' in the constructor", which clearly means instantiation, because only then the constructor is called.  Class C wants to read from class B, while 'v' actually comes from class A, so what's stopping class C from reading 'v'?  And 'v' will change in every instantiation, is that in class A or class B?

Comment: Sorry, You are right. please see the updated version.

Comment: From your code example, why does C need 'v' from B when b1 is a member of A and A is also storing v.  Does C have a reference to an instance of A and can he get 'v' from that?

Comment: Without showing the relationship `C` has to the other classes, there is no way we can help. Maybe you should describe what you want to achieve at a higher level instead.

Comment: Forget about classes. Classes are how you organize code, but when you run it, there are no classes, only objects. There's no "class Person" around, there are Pete, Joe, Jane, Mr and Ms Brown... Do you ever need the residence address of "class Person"? No, you need the residence address of Mr Smith! Static members are OK but they have nothing to do with creation of individual objects. Do you need Mr Smith around in order to access human's number of chromosomes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a 'v' which has never passed to the class. Instead you can make a static copy of it as a member in your class A. It will update every time A is instantiated like this:

```
Class A {
 public:
   int* v;
   static int* staticv;
   ...// Constructor etc
}
```

in your .cc code of A:

```
int* A::staticv;
...
A::staticv=this->v;
```

now any class can access to this value by:

```
A::staticv;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a (public) static member

```
class A { //let's stick with your naming convention!
public:
  static int a;
}

A::a = 4;
```

However allowing people to change A::a means that your program will probably end up relying on a global unencapsulated state... which is usually a sign of a bad design.

If you member was `const` however you are really relating a constant to your class, which is not so bad.

```
class A {
public: 
  static const int a = 4;
}

std::cout << "A:a is always " << A::a << std::endl;
```

**EDIT BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION**
If you require help with building a class I would recommend that you use a factory of some kind. If I understand your requirement you want to be able to inject a value into every class A and class B instance. This value "v" is based on a Class C.

So...

```
class C {
private:
  // up to you where you implement the getUniqueNumberForNow function
  // (global free function for example)
  static const int v = getUniqueNumberForNow();
public:
  static A createA(){
    return A(v);
  }
  static B createB(){
    return B(v);
  }
}
```

The `getUniqueNumberForNow()` function just gets whatever your value should be. It will be then stored in `class C` and can be used during the creation of `A` an\or `B`. Now just make `A` and `B`'s CTORs private and make `C` a `friend` of both and you will have only one way to create an `A` or `B`, and it will always use the correct value.

See NeilMonday's link in the comments below for info on friend classes.

Last thing is if you want to have the value change for every instantiation of `A` you can just do this in the factory:

```
  static A createA(){
    return A(getUniqueNumberForNow());
  }
```

However if that is **really** what you want  then just do this:

```
class A {
public:
  A() : val (getUniqueNumberForNow()), b(B(val)){}
}
```

Comment: how will this handle "'v' will change in every instantiation"?

Comment: You can also use `friend` classes and functions so that they aren't public to everyone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class

Comment: @Computer_guy I've updated the answer to include a way to do what I think you want.

Comment: _“However allowing people to change A::a means that your program will probably end up relying on a global unencapsulated state... which is usually a sign of a bad design.”_ This can be circumvented by using a _private_ static variable `A::a` and a public static getter.